# How to map HList to List[Type], List[TypeTag], or List[String]

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I am playing around with the Scala REPL and its bind method. Unfortunately it takes a ClassTag which erases types some type information, e.g. `List[Int]` becomes `List[_]`. So I want to pass an HList to my REPL wrapper and get the type as a string which I can pass to the bind method. For this I have to map an HList to a List of strings.

```
def extract extends (Tuple2[String, T] ~>> String) {
    def apply[T](value: Tuple2[String, T]) = typeOf[T].toString
}
```

The code above is not working. For one thing I cannot use Tuple2. It should not be too hard to solve that. However, typeOf[T] requires an implicit TypeTag. Any idea how I can doe this? Could `show` help out?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import shapeless._, poly._

object extract extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseT[T: TypeTag] = at[(String, T)](_ => typeOf[T].toString)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import shapeless._
import poly._
defined object extract

scala> val l = ("foo", 23) :: ("bar", true) :: ("baz", 2.0) :: HNil
l: ... = (foo,23) :: (bar,true) :: (baz,2.0) :: HNil

scala> l map extract
res0: String :: String :: String :: HNil = Int :: Boolean :: Double :: HNil
```

Comment: Yep. That did the trick. It took me a while to use this in a method because I wasn't able to define the implicit helper types at first. I have just one questions: When should `def apply[T](...)` be used and when `implicit def caseT[T] ...`? Thanks!